# Why am I getting a Vagrant Puppet "Could not find declared class" Error?

Tags: git, vagrant, puppet

I am trying to use Puppet to set up a gitpull on a Vagrant. I am totally new to authoring Puppet manifests. I have some sample classes which output messages being recognized and working (see helloworld class and subclass in the code below.) But when I try to implement a module that handles git, I am receiving an error message.

**I do have the git module folder located under my manifests folder. Best approach is to take a look at my github link that shows the pp files and folder structure, and see it for yourself. It is here: https://github.com/jamorat/puppet-example **

Here is my site.pp file in its entirety:

```
class { 'sudo': }
class { 'helloworld': }

class sudo {
file { "/etc/sudoers":
    owner => 'root',
    group => 'root',
    mode  => '0440',
}
}

class{ git:
svn => 'installed',
gui => 'installed',
}

class helloworld {
 alert("this is alert. always visible")
 class { helloworld::whoa: }
}

class helloworld::whoa {
alert("another alert from whoa!")
}
```

Here is the error message:

**Puppet::Parser::AST::Resource failed with error ArgumentError: Could not find declared class git at /tmp/vagrant-puppet-1/manifests/site.pp:15 on node vagrant-ubuntu-precise-64.wp.comcast.net**

Probably the best idea is to see this in action. I have created a GitHub repo of the exact manifest I am using. It is here:
https://github.com/jamorat/puppet-example

The manifests and git module are there. If you have Vagrant, this can be `vagrant up` and you will see the error for yourself. Would be cool to either receive an answer here and/or also as a commit (for which credit would still be given here for answer.)

Thank you so much!